# PHP How can I show total data based on Department

Tags: php, mysql

I have a code below :

```
<table>
                    <th class="th1">OT Date</th>
                    <td class="td1"><?php echo $date?></td>
                    <tr>
                    <th class="th" colspan="7">Department</th>
                    <tr>
                    <td class="td1" style="width: 100px;">Accounting</td>
                    <td class="td1" style="width: 100px;">Admin</td>
                    <td class="td1" style="width: 100px;">Facility</td>
                    <td class="td1" style="width: 100px;">IQC</td>
                    <td class="td1" style="width: 100px;">PC</td>
                    <td class="td1" style="width: 100px;">Production</td>
                    <td class="td1" style="width: 100px;">Store</td>
                    <tr>
                    <td class="td">20</td>
                    <td class="td">20</td>
                    <td class="td">20</td>
                    <td class="td">20</td>
                    <td class="td">20</td>
                    <td class="td">20</td>
                    <td class="td">20</td>
                </table>
```

I plan to show total data based on Department. So in table example Admin, will automatically total the data.

and this is the php function code :

```
<?php

include ("config.php");
$dept="Admin";

$pesan = mysql_query("SELECT submission_no FROM t_submissions WHERE dept_name='$dept'");
$j = mysql_num_rows($pesan);
if($j>0)
{
    echo $j;
}
else
{
    echo "no data";
}?>
```

How can I set it if dept=Admin, then it will update total data to admin table, if dept=Accounting, it will update it too and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GROUP BY` with [aggregate functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) in your MySQL query to add or otherwise organize the data by department and then display it in your webpage:

```
SELECT SUM(column_name) FROM t_submissions GROUP BY dept_name;
```

Obviously you will change the query according to your needs.

Comment: I mean is I have a php file in which there are data storage dept_name, so I want every data storage based on submission_no (auto increment) and dept_name, will increase the total data in each department.